How do I get galactic disk thickness as a function of distance from the galactic core? Reading "Galactic Dynamics", Second Edition
I'm trying to ask a good question that other people might wonder about too.
I am looking to calculate the disk thickness as a function of distance. I have my copy of "Galactic Dynamics", Second Edition, and I've read the recommended pages 13, 112, 113, 250-252, 762, 763. I also read pages regarding 'disk thickness'.
No equation jumps out at me.
Edit: Thanks for the answer below. The book says that the disk thickness at the Solar distance is 500 parsecs. I also know the bulge radius. I will interpolate linearly.

I think it's an interesting question but I fear that you'll find that the thickness of the galactic disk is already not well-defined and it will vary greatly between galaxies. Some galaxies aren't even disc-shaped; even referring to the Milky Way in particular you'd have issues defining a hard edge of the disk.

Thank you very much!

The disc thickness is not something that can be calculated, it is measured. It depends on the pre-existing galactic potential, the distribution of material that forms stars and the "heating mechanisms" that gradually modify the dyamics of stars after they are born. The shape or even presence of a disc also clearly depends on the formation history of the Galaxy as a whole, as evidenced by the zoo of different galaxy types, many without discs, that we see in the present universe.

Thank you for your time.
